# center paper-dialog upon opening

Tags: material-design, polymer-1.0, angular, paper-elements

I'm trying to create a simple login window using Angular 2 and Polymer 1.0.2.
It's basically a paper-dialog (login window) with content. The dialog however is not positioned in the center of the screen, see this bugreport [Dialog not centered until window resize #36](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog/issues/36):

The issue suggests calling the `notifyResize()` method on the paper-dialog. But I've no clue as how to refer to the paper-dialog instance in my angular 2/polymer class.

Somehow the import {PaperDialog} is not resolved, but looking in the paper-dialog.html makes me wondering if such an import is possible at all.

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {PaperDialog} from 'bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog';

@Component({
  template: `
    <paper-dialog open> 
    ...  
    </paper-dialog>
  `,
  selector: 'login-window',
  directives : [PaperDialog]
})
export class LoginWindow {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  constructor(){
    this.email = '';
    this.password = '';

    // Where and how to call the PaperDialog child's notifyResize() method
  }
}
```

Note that I'm not opening the dialog programmatically ([fix described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478360/polymer-paper-dialog-not-centered)).
[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29622789/polymer-paper-dialog-position) uses the /deep/ selector that is [deprecated](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120).
And it shouldn't be fixed by applying some css, should it?

Comment: To get a reference of your `PaperDialog` from the `template` property, assuming you have only one you must use [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html) to get a reference to it. It would be useful that you can setup a plnkr to see it more carefuly.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having my code fix the paper-dialog behaviour's code, it's way better to fix the problem itself.
Add the call `this.notifyResize();` to the `_onIronOverlayOpened` method in the [paper-dialog-behavior.html](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog-behavior/blob/master/paper-dialog-behavior.html) source.

```
...
_onIronOverlayOpened: function() {
   if (this.modal) {
     document.body.addEventListener('focus', this._boundOnFocus, true);
     this.backdropElement.addEventListener('click', this._boundOnBackdropClick);
   }
   this.notifyResize(); // Added this line
},
...
```

Although this resolves my simple paper-dialog center problem, I can not oversee consequences for other elements and code yet.

Comment: One can always override the method in paper-dialog with the one you mentioned above. That way it wont interfere with other elements

Answer (score 0):

You could also fix it in the following manner:

Within an angular2 Component (that wraps the paper-dialog element) you could so something like this (Typescript example):

```
interface PaperDialog extends HTMLElement {
    notifyResize(): void;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'login'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: 'app/components/ts-login-window/ts-login-window.html'
})
export class LoginWindow {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    dialogWindow: PaperDialog;

    private bindIronOverlayOpened: EventListenerObject;

    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef){
       this.dialogWindow = elementRef.nativeElement.children[0];

       this.bindIronOverlayOpened = this.ironOverlayOpened.bind(this);
       this.dialogWindow.addEventListener('iron-overlay-opened', this.bindIronOverlayOpened);
    }

    ironOverlayOpened(event: Event) {
        this.dialogWindow.notifyResize();
    }

    onDestroy() {
        this.dialogWindow.removeEventListener('iron-overlay-opened', this.bindIronOverlayOpened);
    }
}
```

Once the paper-dialog has been opened (by the event `iron-overlay-opened`) you could trigger the notifyResize() event on the dialog box. This in turn fixes the alignment problem.